# How retrieve collection of objects from stored procedure which are in database connected with foreign key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, t-sql, stored-procedures

From application, I'm calling stored procedure

```
IEnumerable<ObjectA> AList = this.Context.Database.SqlQuery<A>
      ("EXEC [MyProcedure] @PageSize, @PageNumber, @C, @D, parameters);
```

Reason or that is that I'm passing list of integers from app, and in database I have TVP for cathing them. Now, let's say my class in app looks like this

```
  class A{
   public int ID{get; set;}
   ....
    public virtual ICollection<B> BList{ get; set; } }
```

In my procedure, I'm selecting

```
      Select distinct TableA.*,
             TableB.Id, TableB.Name
```

However, in my app, object A does not have any of objectB in it's collection. How can I select from my procedure to get objects from TableB in collection inside object A?

Comment: Why don't you use regular SQL with an `IN` statement (or `Contains` in LINQ)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need "multiple result sets" from your procedure.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj691402.aspx

```
Select a.Column1, a.Column2, a.Column3 from dbo.TableA a where (your input parameters as filters on TableA)

Select b.Column1, b.Column2, b.Column3, b.Column4, b.TableAColumn1FK from dbo.TableB b where exists ( select null from dbo.TableA a where a.Column1 = b.TableAColumn1FK and (your input parameters as filters on TableA)
```

EF pseudo code

```
using (var db = new MyContext()) 
{ 
    // If using Code First we need to make sure the model is built before we open the connection 
    // This isn't required for models created with the EF Designer 
    db.Database.Initialize(force: false); 

    // Create a SQL command to execute the sproc 
    var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand(); 
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[uspMultiResultsProcedure]"; 

    try 
    { 

        db.Database.Connection.Open(); 
        // Run the sproc  
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 

        // Read Blogs from the first result set 
        var tableAThings = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db) 
            .ObjectContext 
            .Translate<TableA_EFPoco>(reader, "TableA", MergeOption.AppendOnly);    




        // Move to second result set and read Posts 
        reader.NextResult(); 
        var tableBThings = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db) 
            .ObjectContext 
            .Translate<TableB_EFPoco>(reader, "TableBs", MergeOption.AppendOnly); 



    } 
    finally 
    { 
        db.Database.Connection.Close(); 
    } 
}
```

***Note:EF does not take any mapping into account when it creates entities using the Translate method. It will simply match column names in the result set with property names on your classes.***